# Text-based menu to manipulate a database text file

Tags: haskell, io, database, user-interface

I am making a program that lets a user manipulate a database (a text file).

In the code I am posting, I show only 2 of the menu choices, namely "createdb" and "deletedb", and a few functions I made to desperately make the functions more compact. But my problem is that the pattern is similiar for all the other menu options. I ask the user to either enter the name of the database or "b" to return to the menu, and then check if the file exists.

Is there a way I can easily separate this to make my code more compact? I tried to do this part in the menu and have the choice functions be of type

```
FilePath -> IO ()
```

But then my menu looked really terrible. Here is a small part of the code:

```hs
type Choice = (String, String, IO ())

choices :: [Choice]
choices =
    [("a", "create a database", createdb),
    ("b", "delete a database", deletedb),
    ("c", "insert an entry to a database", insert),
    ("d", "print a database", selectall),
    ("e", "select entries from a database", select),
    -- more similiar choices

menu :: IO ()
menu = do
    (mapM_ putStrLn . map showChoice) choices
    c <- get "Enter the letter corresonding to the action of choice:"
    case filter ((== c) . fst3) choices of
    [] -> back "Not a valid choice. Try again"
    (_, _, f) : _ -> f


createdb :: IO ()
createdb = do
    n <- maybeName
    if isNothing n then menu else do
    let name = fromJust n
    fp <- maybeFile name
    if isJust fp
    then back $ "Error: \"" ++ name ++ "\" already exist." 
    else do
        cols <- get "Enter unique column names in the form n1,n2,...,n (No spaces):"
        let spl = (splitOnComma . toLower') cols
        case filter (== True) (hasDuplicates spl : map (elem ' ') spl) of
            [] -> writeFile (name ++ ".txt") (cols ++ "\n")
            _  -> back "Error: Column names must be unique and have no spaces."

deletedb :: IO ()
deletedb = do
    n <- maybeName
    if isNothing n then menu else do
        let name = fromJust n
        fp <- maybeFile name
        if isJust fp
        then removeFile (fromJust fp) 
        else back $ "Error: Could not find " ++ name

maybeName :: IO (Maybe String)
maybeName = do
    input <- get "Enter database name or 'b' to go back to the menu."
    return $ case input of
        "b" -> Nothing
        _   -> Just input 

maybeFile :: String -> IO (Maybe FilePath)
maybeFile name = do
    let fn = name ++ ".txt"
    exists <- doesFileExist fn
    return $ if exists then Just fn else Nothing

back :: String -> IO ()
back msg = do
    putStrLn msg
    menu

get :: String -> IO String
get msg = do
    putStrLn msg
    getLine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do `Maybe FilePath -> IO ()`:

```hs
menu :: IO ()
menu = do
    (mapM_ putStrLn . map showChoice) choices
    c <- get "Enter the letter corresonding to the action of choice:"
    case filter ((== c) . fst3) choices of
    [] -> back "Not a valid choice. Try again"
    (_, _, f) : _ -> maybeName >>= maybe menu (maybeFile >=> f)

createdb :: Maybe FilePath -> IO ()
createdb (Just file) = back $ "Error: \"" ++ file ++ "\" already exists." 
createdb Nothing = do
  cols <- get "Enter unique column names in the form n1,n2,...,n (No spaces):"
  let spl = splitOnComma $ toLower' cols
  if hasDuplicates spl || any (elem ' ') spl
    then back "Error: Column names must be unique and have no spaces."
    else writeFile (name ++ ".txt") (cols ++ "\n")

deletedb :: Maybe FilePath -> IO ()
deletedb Nothing = back $ "Error: Could not find that database."
deletedb (Just file) = removeFile file
```

Comment: Much better. thank you. But is the >=> a typo? Not familiar with that and >>=

Comment: `a >>= b` is another way to write `do x <- a; b x`. `a >=> b` is another way to write `\x -> do y <- a x; b y`. You'll need to import `Control.Monad` for that one.

Comment: I kinda get it. For the 'createdb' function I need the reverse behaviour of all the other functions however. I tried to write it and ended up with this: ("a", _, f) : _ -> getName >>= maybe menu (\x -> do y <- getFile x; if isJust y then f Nothing else f (Just x))

Any better way to write this?

Comment: Doesn't my implementation above already do that?

Comment: The  createdb does writeFile name ++ ".txt" but I need the name